# React: Trying to set an API JSON response to state object and pass it to component for mapping and rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a component where I've set an empty array called `customers: []` in `this.setState: { }`. On load the component fires a POST call to an API which returns a JSON object with the XHR name *CustomerOffers*. I have logic in place to iterate through the array and map all parts of the JSON object to the UI but every time I load the app I'm getting an Error message stating `TypeError: this.state.customers.map is not a function`, but when I tested this with dummy data inside the customers array everything rendered properly. I used a console.log statement to print the return response from the API and it's showing as undefined which leads me to believe that somewhere in the return process the app isn't getting the data. I've included my code below, any help on this would be huge!

React

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Button.css';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import axios from 'axios';

class UsersList extends Component {


  constructor(){
        super();
        // this.selectCard  = this.selectCard.bind(this);
        // Define data model object and cardActive 
        this.state = {

            cardActive: null,

            dataModel: {
              offerName: null,
              customerId: null
            },

            SessionId: null,

            customers: []
        }



        // this.updateOffer = offerID => {};

        this.submitData = () => {
          let temporalDataModel = this.state.dataModel;

          temporalDataModel.SessionId = this.state.SessionId;

          console.log(
            "Transmitting data...NOW",
            temporalDataModel
          );

          this.setState(
            {
              dataModel: temporalDataModel
            },
            () => {
              let postUrl = "https://myAPI.com";
              axios
                .post(postUrl, this.state.dataModel)
                .then(response => {
                  console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.error(err);
                });
            }
          );
        };

        this.selectCard = obj => {
          let temporalDataModel = this.state.dataModel;

        //   console.log("paramenters", obj);
        //   console.log("currentState", temporalDataModel);

          this.state.customers.forEach(c => {
            if (c.CustomerId === obj.customerId) {
              c.Offers.forEach(off => {
                if (off.OfferId === obj.offerId) {
                  console.log("offer", off);
                  temporalDataModel.customerId = obj.customerId;
                  temporalDataModel.offerName = off.Name;
                  temporalDataModel.offerId = off.OfferId;
                  temporalDataModel.products = off.Products;
                  temporalDataModel.sessionId = obj.SessionId;
                }
              });
            }
          });

          console.log("data updated", temporalDataModel);

          this.setState({ cardActive: obj.offerId, SessionId: obj.SessionId,  });
        };
    }


    getCustomerOffers(){
      var search = window.location.search;
      var params = new URLSearchParams(search);
      var customerId = params.get('CUSTOMERID');
      var sessionId = params.get('SESSIONID');
      var data = "{'CustomerId':'1','SessionId':'9636','IsExisting':'true'}";

      var requestOffers = { 
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://myAPI.com',
        data: "{'CustomerId':'" + customerId + "','SessionId':'" + sessionId + "'}"
    };


          axios.post('https://myAPI.com',
               "{'CustomerId':'" + customerId + "','SessionId':'" + sessionId + "'}")
           .then((res) => {
               console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
               this.setState({
                   customers: res.data
               });
               console.log("Customer: ", this.state.customers.CustomerId);
           })
           .catch((err) => {
               console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
           });

    }


    componentDidMount(){
      this.getCustomerOffers();

    }


    // selectCard(offerId) {   
    //     this.setState({ cardActive: offerId });
    //   }


    render (){
        return (
          this.state.customers != null && 
          <div>
          {this.state.customers.map((customer, index) => {
              return  <div key={index + customer.CustomerId}>

                              <h3 >Name: {customer.LastName}, {customer.FirstName}</h3>
                              <h3 >Customer ID: {customer.CustomerId}</h3>
                              <h3 >
                              Address: 
                              <br></br>
                              {customer.Address.Address1}
                              <br></br>
                              {customer.Address.City}, {customer.Address.State} {customer.Address.Zip} 
                              </h3>
                              <br></br>
                              <h2>Available Offers</h2>
                              <Grid container spacing={24} justify="center"> 
                              {customer.Offers.map((Offer,index) => {
                                  return <div key={index + Offer.OfferId} onClick={() => {
                                      const obj = {
                                        offerId: Offer.OfferId,
                                        customerId: customer.CustomerId,
                                      };
                                      console.log("Offer ID:",Offer.OfferId, ",Customer ID:",customer.CustomerId,",Offer Name:", Offer.OfferName, ",Session ID:", customer.SessionId);
                                      this.selectCard(obj);
                                    }}>
                                          <Grid item xs={12}>
                                          <div className={Offer.OfferId === this.state.cardActive ? "cardActive" : "card"}>
                                              <div className="container">
                                                  <h5><b>{Offer.OfferId}</b></h5> 
                                                  <h2>{Offer.Name}</h2>
                                                  {Offer.Products.map((Product, index) => {
                                                      return <div key={index + Product.ProductId}>
                                                              <p>+ {Product.ProductName}</p>
                                                            </div>

                                                  })}
                                                  <h3>{Offer.Price}</h3> 
                                              </div>
                                          </div>
                                          </Grid>

                                      </div>
                              })}

                              </Grid>

                      </div>

          })}

          <button className="navbuttonSelected" disabled={!this.state.cardActive} onClick={this.submitData}>Submit</button>

      </div>
        )

    }
}

export default UsersList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are using Axios (or try and catch) quite how it should be for asynchronous requests.

Try and Catch blocks can only be used on synchronous blocks of code. When you make an api call is it asynchronous (i.e. takes a random amount of time to complete). To catch an error on an asynchronous block, you would normally use a .catch(handlerFunction) attached to a promise.

It should be something like:

```
axios.post(myurl, mydata).then(res => console.log(res))
   .catch(e => console.log(e))
```

So getOffer might be rewritten:

```
const getOffers = (trequest) => {
    return axios(trequest)
      .catch(e => console.log(e) );
}
```

To get the results, you would then need to do something like:

```
getOffers('/getmyoffers').then(results => console.log(results) )
```

Edit - to update the customers state you can do this:

```
getOffers('/getmyoffers').then(results => this.setState({customers:results.data} )
```

Comment: Is there a CodeSandbox you could share with that implementation? I updated my code to reflect this and the page is rendering but none of the data is mapping or displaying. Is there a way to push the JSON object inside of the empty array I've set for customers?

Comment: Answer updated - if this solved your problem, please mark as correct!

Comment: I implemented this logic and updated my example code above to reflect the changes but now I'm getting an error saying `TypeError: this.state.customers.map is not a function` whenever I run this. Yesterday I hardcoded everything to reflect `this.state.customer` and removed the mapping functionality and everything rendered correctly which leads me to believe the customers array is still not populating. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: when setting customers, have you checked the format of the 'results' var? It may be that you need to use results.data or something

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside your `getCustomerOffers` method. In this method you are setting `customers` state to a promise which causing the `render` method to be re-executed, at this point, `this.state.customers` is no longer an array (a promise instead).

So now if you understand the root cause, the fix will be easy like someone already posted:

```
axios(trequest).then((response) => {
   this.setState({ customers: response.data });
}, e => {
   console.log(e);
});
```

I strongly recommend reading more about Javascript Asynchronous as it will help you more in the long run.